# Detect Chrome extension on $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, document-ready

in my website i want to detect, wheter my chrome-extension is installed or not.
Usually one would use a custom script to create some

```
<div id="extensionExists"></div>.
```

However, i want to detect the extension before the websites javascript runs.
Since i don't want to wait for images to be fully loaded, i'm using document.ready() instead of window.onload().
However, i fail to create a div beforehand.
If my content script uses run_at:"document start", i can't create div's yet, if i use "document end", it is too late, the document.ready() has already run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Mhh... there is no clean solution as far as I know. My only idea is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) to access the document before it was fully loaded but I don't have the time to properly test it right now...

```
var obs = new WebKitMutationObserver(function ( mutations ) {
  console.log( mutations );
  mutations.forEach(function ( mutation ) {
    var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
    console.log( newNodes );
    // newNodes should now contain a NodeList which contains all nodes that were created right now
    // you should be able to create your element now
    // consider using obs.disconnect(); after you have found your entry point.
  });
});

obs.observe( document, { childList: true } );
```

No guarantee it'll do anything. jsFiddle doesn't allow to add a script before the document so I couldn't even test it there.

Comment: Doesn't do anything sadly.
My way now is to redirect from the webpage to a modified copy
of it in the extension.
Not the best but works, worst thing is, that the pages
from the extension don't have a path in the omnibox.
(Not even sth. like extension:main.html)